# Java Swing - Draw graphics inside of a Panel

Tags: java, swing

I took this piece of code from my software. I have a panel called pnlUserInfo. Inside of it, I have another panel called pnlStatistikat, which has yet another panel inside it (just for graphics) called pnGrafika. In the first lines of code, I draw something and then I have no idea how to wrap it inside pnGrafik. (How to call this class Grafika inside of pnGrafik, so the object can be shown)

```
class Grafika extends JPanel{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillArc(0, 0, 100, 100, 0, (int)pnUserInfo.tOL);
    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    g.fillArc(0, 0, 100, 100, (int)pnUserInfo.tOL, (int)pnUserInfo.tOK);
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.fillArc(0, 0, 100, 100, (int)pnUserInfo.tOK+(int)pnUserInfo.tOL, (int)pnUserInfo.tOS);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillArc(0, 0, 100, 100, (int)pnUserInfo.tOK+(int)pnUserInfo.tOL+(int)pnUserInfo.tOS, (int)pnUserInfo.tOP);
    }
}

public class pnUserInfo extends JPanel {
   public pnUserInfo() {

    final JPanel pnlStatistikat = new JPanel();
    pnlStatistikat.setBounds(0, 0, 530, 628);
    pnlProfiliKryesor.add(pnlStatistikat);
    pnlStatistikat.setBackground(myColor);
    pnlStatistikat.setLayout(null);
    pnlStatistikat.setVisible(false);

    JPanel pnGrafik = new JPanel();
    pnGrafik.setBounds(250, 30, 110, 110);
    pnGrafik.add(new Grafika());
    pnlStatistikat.add(pnGrafik);
    pnGrafik.setBackground(myColor);
    pnGrafik.setLayout(null);
    pnGrafik.setVisible(true);
 }}
```

Comment: Please post [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See comments :

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class Grafika extends JPanel{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillArc(0, 0, 100, 100, 0, 30);
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillArc(0, 0, 100, 100, 30, 50);
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillArc(0, 0, 100, 100, 50, 90);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillArc(0, 0, 100, 100, 90,120);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(300,250);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new pnUserInfo());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class pnUserInfo extends JPanel {

    public pnUserInfo() {

        setLayout(null);//missing

        JPanel pnlStatistikat = new JPanel();
        pnlStatistikat.setLayout(null);
        pnlStatistikat.setBounds(0, 0, 300, 250);
        pnlStatistikat.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        add(pnlStatistikat); //missing
        //remove pnlStatistikat.setVisible(false);

        JPanel pnGrafik = new JPanel();
        pnGrafik.setLayout(null);
        pnGrafik.setBounds(50, 50, 200, 200);
        pnGrafik.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

        Grafika graf = new Grafika();
        graf.setBounds(30, 30, 110, 110);//missing
        pnGrafik.add(graf);

        pnlStatistikat.add(pnGrafik);
        pnGrafik.setVisible(true);
    }}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's simple

```
pnGraphik.add(new Graphika());
```

Comment: Still not working. I moved Grafika inside of pnUserInfo() because it wasnt recognizing it, but still the panel is there (pnGrafik), but no graphic. :(

Comment: Did you set the layouts of the panels to null, or to your desired layout?

Comment: As you can see, every panel object has null layout as desired.

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.